# how to implement abstract factory in rust?

Tags: rust

Something like:

```
trait Thingy {
    fn hallo(&self);
}

trait Factory {
    fn make(&self) -> Thingy;
}
//------------------------------
struct AThingy {}

impl Thingy for AThingy {
    fn hallo(&self) {
        println!("i'm A thingy");
    }
}

struct AFactory {}

impl Factory for AFactory {
    fn make(&self) -> AThingy {
        AThingy{}
    }
}

//------------------------------
struct BThingy {}

impl Thingy for BThingy {
    fn hallo(&self) {
        println!("i'm B thingy");
    }
}

struct BFactory {}

impl Factory for BFactory {
    fn make(&self) -> BThingy {
        BThingy{}
    }
}

//------------------------------
#[test]
fn test_factory() {
    let aFactory:Factory = AFactory{};
    let bFactory:Factory = BFactory{};
    
    aFactory.make().hallo();
    bFactory.make().hallo();
}
```

tried to attach Sized at various places but all fails.

Comment: You factory trait, implement a function that returns a trait?

Comment: You will need to make your factory method return a `Box<dyn Trait>` OR make the type of the thing it constructs an associated type of the Factory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `Thingy` is a trait, this:

```
fn make(&self) -> Thingy;
```

is equivalent to:

```
fn make(&self) -> dyn Thingy;
```

That is, an *unsized* bare trait object. You cannot deal with unsized types like that in Rust; trait objects need to be behind a pointer of some kind. Given that the function creates the object, it can't be a `&dyn Thingy`, so you'll need an *owned* pointer, like `Box<dyn Thingy>`.

So your `Factory` trait will look like this:

```
trait Factory {
    fn make(&self) -> Box<dyn Thingy>;
}
```

And implementations look like this:

```
impl Factory for AFactory {
    fn make(&self) -> Box<dyn Thingy> {
        Box::from(AThingy{})
    }
}
```

---

Given your question, I would guess you are trying to apply patterns that you are used to from object-oriented languages, like Java. These patterns go against the idioms that are commonly used in Rust, and force you to box data, that probably wouldn't otherwise need to be boxed. In Java, almost everything generic is boxed, and you pay for that.

Comment: btw, 
>You cannot deal with unsized types like
- do I understand correctly that it's because rust can't build vtable when struct has functions with Traits (unsized) and it's going to be fixed?

Comment: yep, I'm from java :)  what then would be an appropriate rust idiom for abstract factory?

Comment: @user656449 Factories are still a valid Rust pattern, but they would generally be modelled as a trait with an associated `Output`, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: To actually answer the question posed in the original comment, (AFAIK) this is not so much a vtable issue as a question of storing data on the stack. You can't create an unsized local variable in ANY language (again, AFAIK). Instead, you allocate on the heap at runtime (when you know how big the result will be) and store the address in the local stack frame in a pointer (Box), which IS sized. So no, not a bug or a deficiency that will some day get fixed.

Answer (score 10):

You can use *associated types*. `Factory` can have an associated type called `Output`. You can add a bound that requires `Output` to implement `Thingy`:

```rust
trait Factory {
    type Output: Thingy;
    
    fn make(&self) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Now, `AFactory`'s `Output` will be `AThingy`:

```rust
impl Factory for AFactory {
    type Output = AThingy;
    
    fn make(&self) -> AThingy {
        AThingy {}
    }
}
```

And `BFactory`'s `Output` will be `BThingy`:

```rust
impl Factory for BFactory {
    type Output = BThingy;
    
    fn make(&self) -> BThingy {
        BThingy {}
    }
}
```

As @PeterHall mentioned, you cannot deal with unsized types in Rust, so to store a `Factory` you need to use an *owned* pointer like `Box<dyn Factory>`:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_factory() {
    let aFactory: Box<dyn Factory> = Box::new(AFactory {});
    let bFactory: Box<dyn Factory> = Box::new(BFactory {});

    aFactory.make().hallo();
    bFactory.make().hallo();
}
```

However, because `Factory` has an associated type, you also have to specify the `Output` when making it into a trait object:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_factory() {
    let aFactory: Box<dyn Factory<Output = AThingy>> = Box::new(AFactory {});
    let bFactory: Box<dyn Factory<Output = BThingy>> = Box::new(BFactory {});

    aFactory.make().hallo();
    bFactory.make().hallo();
}
```

Comment: When using an associated type, is it somehow still possible to turn the factories into `Box<dyn Thingy>` factories, i.e., have a dynamic factory like `let factory_a_or_b = if use_a { aFactory } else { bFactory }`? Or does this require the approach suggested by @PeterHall?

Comment: [Answer converted into Rust Playground for experimentation.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b54052ebaac5a39e1770356376b1dfc2)